# How to extract desired content from a log file?

Tags: regex, perl

Assume I have a log file and its format looks like:

```
02-02 23:55:41.481  2050 21652 D [LOGGRAB]: [CPU temp average]: 60.98750352859497
```

I would like to have my output as =>

```
"02-02" "23:55:41.481"  "2050" "21652" "D" "LOGGRAB" "CPU temp average" "60.98750352859497"
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Perl regular expressions tutorial](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) is a good place to start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While we're happy to help with specific coding problems, please note that we're not here to write your scripts for you. I recommend you take a look at a good Perl tutorial (or, if you already know the basics, the link negacao posted is excellent) and give it a shot yourself. If you make an attempt and have trouble with some specific part of the script, then feel free to come back and ask a question about that. See also [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for what sorts of questions are in scope. Good luck!

Comment: *Is there any way to achieve my goal?* The answer is "yes, there is". The first question is, why do you need it? The second is what problems did you have using Perl Regex to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard, try this

```
echo "02-02 23:55:41.481 2050 21652 D [LOGGRAB]: [CPU temp average]: 60.98750352859497" | perl -lpe 's/\[(.*?)\]:|([\S]+)/"\1\2"/g;'
```

output:

> "02-02" "23:55:41.481" "2050" "21652" "D" "LOGGRAB" "CPU temp average"
> "60.98750352859497"